# How to build an Electric Vehicle (explain like I'm five)

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, controller, electric-machine

I'm a business major investing time to learn more about Electric Vehicles. For starters, I wanted to understand the elements that come together to make a simple Electric Vehicle, maybe a scooter.
I saw a video which helped me get a very basic idea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFWEc7Ytq44

Next I spoke to some of my Electrical Engineer friends who told me about Brush & Brushless motors, they tried to explain the difference between AC/DC motors and bunch of other stuff about controllers having to be much smarter than the one in the video for an Electric Vehicle.

Everything put together, I know to some extent what those elements need to be, but I don't know where to start and what to buy. I know there could be many ways of achieving the same result, I'm just hoping to get started.

Can you please point me in the right direction with what I should be purchasing and which parts I need to put together for eventually creating something I can ride around in my neighborhood?

Please explain like I'm five.

Update: I expect the scooter to ride on flat but uneven/bumpy Indian Roads. Ability to climb basic slopes to get on city bridges is a good to have. Surely something that is rain proof.

Comment: Write a specification of what you want to achieve i.e. how the vehicle is expected to perform on the flat, uphill, with various loads etc.. What rates of acceleration are needed, top speed, battery life.

Comment: @Andyaka I've added the update. 

I expect the scooter to ride on flat but uneven/bumpy Indian Roads. Ability to climb basic slopes to get on city bridges is a good to have. Surely something that is rain proof. 

Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry but you are going to have to do much better than that dude.

Comment: @Andyaka I thought I might have to give specifics.
To be completely honest, I've just started reading about things like:
• Startability
• Gradeability
• Acceleration Capability
• Stopping Distance
• Down-grade Holding Capability

I'm guessing you're looking for those specs, right?
I've not been able to decide what it should be for the vehicle I'm trying to build. Simply because I've not built something like this before.

Can you tell me where I can start to make these decisions?

Comment: I have no idea what those things are. I'll try and explain in the form of an answer....

Comment: @AkhilAryan you don't need to include INDIAN roads. Indian roads are great.!

Answer (score 5):

This isn't really an answer but a guide to help the op understand what he has to comprehend.

You have a scooter that maybe weighs 100 kg. You have a guy riding it who might weigh 50 kg. You might want a top speed of 40 mph (18 m/s). You might want to attain that speed in 10 seconds from a standstill.

Average acceleration is 18 m/s per 10 seconds = 1.8 m/s\$^2\$

Force = mass x acceleration = 150 kg x 1.8 m/s\$^2\$ = 270 newtons

The distance travelled to get up to 18 m/s is the average speed (9 m/s) x 10 seconds  = 90 m.

Total work = force x distance = 270 N x 90 m joules = 24.3 kJ.

Power = joules per second = 24.3 kJ / 10 seconds = 2.43 kW.

This basically tells you how big your motor needs to be. So if you run from a 12 V battery, the current expected from that battery might be 202.5 amps. This tells you a bit more about the choice of motor and about how thick the wires need to be.

You can then go on to make several assumptions about the average current drawn on a typical journey. Never underestimate how complex this is to do because every time you stop at a junction you have "lost" all your energy and have to put it back again in order to attain 40 mph.

So, develop a model of a typical journey and you might conclude that the average current for that journey is 100 amps (guesswork by me). The average journey time might be 1 hour.

From this you can calculate the capacity of the battery i.e. 100 ampere-hours. It's starting to sound a lot like a big car battery to me but it's never that simple. Things are never 100 % efficient and the unexpected does happen. You might not be able to recharge your battery from the return journey and therefore you have to "carry" more capacity.

Anyway, these are the things you need to intially think about. The "paint job" comes last.